# Unexpected unknown pseudo-element selector "::ng-deep"

Tags: angular, angular-material, sonarqube

I am trying to overwrite the angular material so I used ::ng-deep but is getting error in sonarqube.
please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: Hi, please be more concise with your problem, and show some of the code you've tried and the error you're getting.

Comment: Did you find any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 10):

In your stylelint config (in this example .stylelintrc.json) add the following rule:

```json
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": [true, { "ignorePseudoElements": ["ng-deep"] }]
  }
}
```

This will allow `ng-deep` pseudo element without disabling the rule

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, as it doesn't turn off the rule entirely, but just specific selectors.

Answer (score 2):

SonarQube [should respect](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-css/issues/151#issuecomment-487517463) .stylelintrc. We tried a few versions, none of which worked. Our current is JSON which doesn't work either:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "selector-type-no-unknown": null,
    "selector-pseudo-element-no-unknown": null
  }
}
```

I know this isn't a very helpful answer, but it's all I know so far.

Answer (score -3):

try it like this

```
:host {

  ::ng-deep {

    //css

  }
```

If we want our component styles to cascade to all child elements of a component, but not to any other element on the page, we can currently do so using by combining the :host with the ::ng-deep selector:

```
:host ::ng-deep h2 {
    color: red;
}
```

This will generate at runtime a style that looks like this:

```
<style>  
[_nghost-c0]  h2 {
    color: red;
}
</style>
}
```

Comment: :host also getting same

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular, it's SonarQube issue.